# CSS child in grid forcing parent to overflow

Tags: html, css

I am working with a CSS code and I have ran into some trouble.

1. The `<div class='module'>` should be 100% of the height left remaining inside of the `<div class='area'>` and the "module" should be scrollable if necessary. However, right now, the module is forcing it's parent to expand instead of having a scrollbar. Why is this? Here is a [picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urbQZ.jpg) for the desired end result.
2. I want the entire page to be scrollable so the user can scroll down to see the `<div class='area spotlight'>` but right now the page is almost stuck at being 100vh, no scroll allowed. Why is this?

I have tried adding max-height, `overflow: auto` and `position: relative` to both the child and parent classes without any success.

I am feeling pretty frustrated with CSS so would love some help. Any explanations and solutions so I can learn would be greatly appreciated.

```css
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100vw; height: 65px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5F6368;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  /* ----------[GENERAL]---------- */

  body {background-color: #FDFDFD;}

  #content {
    display: grid;
    position: fixed;
    top: 65px; left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    padding: 0px 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 110px 1fr 90px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "hello hello"
      "announce feed"
      "spotlight spotlight";}

/* This formats the margin & placement of the boxes */
#content .area {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;}

#content area .heading {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #484848}

/* This formats the module boxes */
#content .module {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px #CECECE;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100%}

/* ----------[HELLO HEADER]---------- */
.hello {
  grid-area: hello;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;}

.hello .title {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #484848}

/* Handles button spacing & size */
.hello .topbtn {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 1px 1.2px #CECECE;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;}
  .topbtn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.03);
    background-color: #D4BBF1}

/* ----------[ANNOUNCEMENTS]---------- */
  .announce {grid-area: announce;}

  .announce .board {
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;}

  /* Each message formatting */
  .announce .board section {
    padding: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  .announce .board .msg {font-size: 14.5px}

  /* Bottom part of message formatting */
  .announce section .details {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-size: 13px}

  .announce section .details img {
    width: 25px;
    clip-path: circle();
    margin-right: 10px}

  .announce section .details .date {
    flex: 1;
    color: gray;
    text-align: right}


/* ----------[GRADE FEED]---------- */
.feed {grid-area: feed;}

/* -- Makes list scrollable -- */
.feed .list {overflow: auto}

/* -- Resets default values -- */
.feed .list ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;}

/* -- Styling for each list item -- */
.feed .list li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;}

/* Stylize grades */
.A-font {font-weight: 800; color: #5B7042}
.B-font {font-weight: 800; color: #88A465}
.C-font {font-weight: 800; color: #D17010}
.D-font {font-weight: 800; color: #d5ab09}
.F-font {font-weight: 800; color: #AD1A2A}



/* ----------[SPOTLIGHT]---------- */
.spotlight {grid-area: spotlight;}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
  <nav></nav>
</head>

<div id="content">
  
  <div class='hello'>
    <div class='title'>Hi, Student.</div>
    <div class='topbtn overdue'> check in</div>
    <div class='topbtn mail'>✉️ 3 new messages</div>
    <div class='topbtn overdue'> 1 overdue task</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='area announce'>
    <div class='heading'>Announcements</div>
    <div class='module board'>
         <section>
           <div class='msg'>Please do not leave comments on Google Classroom - I more than likely will not see it. If you need me, use Clever or the "Ask for Help" button on ClassColonies to ask me questions.</div>
           <div class='details'>
             <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'>
             <span class='name'>Mr. Teacher</span>
             <span class='date'>1w ago</span>
           </div>
         </section>
         <section>
           <div class='msg'>You do not need to write on the assignment today. I printed this off for you last week. If you lost your paper, write your answers on a separate piece of paper to bring to class on Tuesday.</div>
           <div class='details'>
             <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'>
             <span class='name'>Mr. Teacher</span>
             <span class='date'>1w ago</span>
           </div>
         </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='area feed'>
    <div class='heading'>Recent Grades</div>
    <div class='module list'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class='title'>✏️ Thoughts, Actions, Words</span>
          <span class='subject'>Social Studies</span>
          <span class='score B-font'>8/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Flocab: Text Structure</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score C-font'>7/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Main Idea Bag Scoot</span>
          <span class='subject'>Social Studies</span>
          <span class='score F-font'>2/5</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'>✏️ Thoughts, Actions, Words</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score B-font'>8/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Flocab: Text Structure</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score C-font'>7/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Main Idea Bag Scoot</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score F-font'>2/5</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'>✏️ Thoughts, Actions, Words</span>
          <span class='subject'>Social Studies</span>
          <span class='score B-font'>8/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Flocab: Text Structure</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score C-font'>7/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Main Idea Bag Scoot</span>
          <span class='subject'>Social Studies</span>
          <span class='score F-font'>2/5</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'>✏️ Thoughts, Actions, Words</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score B-font'>8/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Flocab: Text Structure</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score C-font'>7/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Main Idea Bag Scoot</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score F-font'>2/5</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='area spotlight'>
    <div class='heading'>Recent Shoutouts</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm reading the problem correctly. However, the elements seem as if they are fixed at `100vh` because of your `height: calc(100%-65px);` on your `body`. Once you remove that, your page should scroll as expected. I added more `li`'s under `module overdue` for demonstration purposes.

**EDIT** -- wrong code posted. New code - you're using `position: fixed;` on your `content id` fixed does not allow for any scrolling especially on the main parent. Use `marign-top` on `hello` and `area` to move elements down. Added dummy image to demonstrate scroll.

Also, may I suggest `z-index: -1;` on `area` so `content` elements tucked behind menu on scroll?

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100vw; height: 65px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5F6368;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  /* ----------[GENERAL]---------- */

  body {background-color: #FDFDFD;}

  #content {
    display: grid;
    top: 65px; left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    padding: 0px 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 110px 1fr 90px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "hello hello"
      "announce feed"
      "spotlight spotlight";}

/* This formats the margin & placement of the boxes */
#content .area {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 46%;
}

#content area .heading {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #484848}

/* This formats the module boxes */
#content .module {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px #CECECE;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100%}

/* ----------[HELLO HEADER]---------- */
.hello {
  grid-area: hello;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.hello .title {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #484848}

/* Handles button spacing & size */
.hello .topbtn {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 1px 1.2px #CECECE;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;}
  .topbtn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.03);
    background-color: #D4BBF1}

/* ----------[ANNOUNCEMENTS]---------- */
  .announce {grid-area: announce;}

  .announce .board {
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;}

  /* Each message formatting */
  .announce .board section {
    padding: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  .announce .board .msg {font-size: 14.5px}

  /* Bottom part of message formatting */
  .announce section .details {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-size: 13px}

  .announce section .details img {
    width: 25px;
    clip-path: circle();
    margin-right: 10px}

  .announce section .details .date {
    flex: 1;
    color: gray;
    text-align: right}


/* ----------[GRADE FEED]---------- */
.feed {grid-area: feed;}

/* -- Makes list scrollable -- */
.feed .list {overflow: auto}

/* -- Resets default values -- */
.feed .list ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;}

/* -- Styling for each list item -- */
.feed .list li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;}

/* Stylize grades */
.A-font {font-weight: 800; color: #5B7042}
.B-font {font-weight: 800; color: #88A465}
.C-font {font-weight: 800; color: #D17010}
.D-font {font-weight: 800; color: #d5ab09}
.F-font {font-weight: 800; color: #AD1A2A}



/* ----------[SPOTLIGHT]---------- */
.spotlight {grid-area: spotlight;}

.spotlight {
  position: relative;
  top: -23rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
  <nav></nav>
</head>

<div id="content">
  
  <div class='hello'>
    <div class='title'>Hi, Student.</div>
    <div class='topbtn overdue'> check in</div>
    <div class='topbtn mail'>✉️ 3 new messages</div>
    <div class='topbtn overdue'> 1 overdue task</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='area announce'>
    <div class='heading'>Announcements</div>
    <div class='module board'>
         <section>
           <div class='msg'>Please do not leave comments on Google Classroom - I more than likely will not see it. If you need me, use Clever or the "Ask for Help" button on ClassColonies to ask me questions.</div>
           <div class='details'>
             <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'>
             <span class='name'>Mr. Teacher</span>
             <span class='date'>1w ago</span>
           </div>
         </section>
         <section>
           <div class='msg'>You do not need to write on the assignment today. I printed this off for you last week. If you lost your paper, write your answers on a separate piece of paper to bring to class on Tuesday.</div>
           <div class='details'>
             <img src='https://classcolonies.com/resources/pics/teachers/1.jpg'>
             <span class='name'>Mr. Teacher</span>
             <span class='date'>1w ago</span>
           </div>
         </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='area feed'>
    <div class='heading'>Recent Grades</div>
    <div class='module list'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class='title'>✏️ Thoughts, Actions, Words</span>
          <span class='subject'>Social Studies</span>
          <span class='score B-font'>8/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Flocab: Text Structure</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score C-font'>7/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Main Idea Bag Scoot</span>
          <span class='subject'>Social Studies</span>
          <span class='score F-font'>2/5</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'>✏️ Thoughts, Actions, Words</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score B-font'>8/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Flocab: Text Structure</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score C-font'>7/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Main Idea Bag Scoot</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score F-font'>2/5</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'>✏️ Thoughts, Actions, Words</span>
          <span class='subject'>Social Studies</span>
          <span class='score B-font'>8/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Flocab: Text Structure</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score C-font'>7/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Main Idea Bag Scoot</span>
          <span class='subject'>Social Studies</span>
          <span class='score F-font'>2/5</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'>✏️ Thoughts, Actions, Words</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score B-font'>8/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Flocab: Text Structure</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score C-font'>7/10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class='title'> Main Idea Bag Scoot</span>
          <span class='subject'>Reading</span>
          <span class='score F-font'>2/5</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='area spotlight'>
    <div class='heading'>Recent Shoutouts</div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=I+scrolled!!">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: My apologizes - I copied the wrong script.. this is what looking at code for 3 hours will do for you, haha! Updated OG post.

Comment: @Mathew Updated! I was confused on screenshot mainly... explains it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! This fixes the second problem, but doesn't help resolve the main first problem. The final result should look something like this [image](https://imgur.com/a/ziUMC23) but instead the "recent grades" section is extremely long. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Mathew see the adjusted, just like screenshot.